# OOP: Methods concatenation and check the "queue"

Tags: php, oop

I have this problem: I want to concatenate more methods, but I need that a method ( the first ), if there's another method after, returns $this, otherwise return an object.

Examples:

```
$some->create( 'Foo' )->with( 'Bar' );
$some->create( 'Foo' );
```

In the first example, `$some->create()` has to return $this to permit the concatenation.
In the second, the method `create()` has to return an object.

Is there a way without change the methods order? Now I return always $this and then you can obtain that object "returned" with another function ( example: `$some->create( 'Foo' )->getInfo();` )

Thanks.

Comment: It is called **method chainig**.

Comment: This is not helpful. The question is another. I know how to do method chaining, but I don't know how (and if it's possible ) to return different values if there's another method after the first.

Comment: The code evaluates left to right, so the `create()` method can never know that there is an additional method call to `with()` that will be executed after it has been called

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use the `with()` call before the `create()` call, using the `with()` method to set some property of the `$some` class so that `create()` knows how it needs to execute based on that property... `$some->with('Bar')->create('Foo');` and `$some->create('Foo');` could then perform differently based on whether the `with` property had been set

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, but I wrote "without change the methods order".. This solution is the one I adopted before ahah!

Comment: Unless you want to pass an extra argument to `create()`, then the answer is a simple word, "No"

Answer (score 1):

Your method `create()` may return anything, but has no information about what the calling method does with it.
Possible options are to pass an optional argument or to use a wrapper method.

```
class Test {
    public function create($what, $methodChaining = false)
    {
        // do stuff, create $object
        if ($methodChaining) {
            return $this;
        }
        return $object;
    }

    public function createAndChain($what)
    {
        $this->create($what);
        return $this;
    }
}

$object->create('Foo', true)->with('Bar'); // execute with() on the first $object
$object->createAndChain('Foo')->with('Bar'); // same as above
$object->create('Foo')->with('Bar'); // execute with() from the new Foo-object
```

Furthermore, the code can't know if you want to execute the chained methods on the first one object or the new created one..